# [ERROR]: Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
cursor.execute(
"SELECT * FROM `xplt_cases` LEFT JOIN `dgn_cases` ON dgn_cases.rid = xplt_cases.rid WHERE `status`=%(checker)s",
{
  'checker': status
})
```

I'm new to MySQL and I'm trying to join two tables together to grab the results, but I'm getting an error saying: Column `status` in where clause is ambiguous.

["status" is my function argument.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnzJy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error `Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous` means that the 2 tables you joined in your query have both a column named `status` that's why `Mysql` tells you that the `column status is ambiguous`

You can fix this by indicating the table which `status` column you want to use in your query. Examples;

```
  xplt_cases.`status`=%(checker)s"
```

or

```
   dgn_cases.`status`=%(checker)s"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems both of your tables have a `status` column. Try prefixing it with a table name(alias):

```
SELECT * FROM `xplt_cases` x LEFT JOIN `dgn_cases` ON dgn_cases.rid = xplt_cases.rid 
WHERE x.`status`=%(checker)s
```